# Xcode - How to add xib launch screen without changing the UIScreen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios8

My current project having the Default-568h.png as launch screen and when I checked my `UIScreen.mainscreen.bound` is width:320 and height:568 for all devices.

I added .xib file as my launch screen but the issue is the `UIScreen.mainscreen.bound` no longer as width:320 and height:568 and it follow the devices size.

How do I always fix the `UIScreen.mainscreen.bound` is 320x568 ?

Comment: Why not adapt to the `launchscreen.xib` or `.storyboard`?

Answer (score 1):

Adding a .xib or .storyboard file as the launch screen file will cause the device not to scale the app as you might expect anymore. If your launch screen is static, then just convert it to an image and set that as the launch screen image. After that it will keep the bounds you are expecting. You can put your 1x 2x and 3x images in a xcassets folder and set that as the Launch Images source also.

Comment: the reason of using xib is because of I needed to add a text view of the version number. So when there is a new version, I can change the version number in xib instead of changing the image using photoshop.

Comment: You can then create the splash screen in photoshop without the version number and make the first screen of your app be the exact same as the splash screen with the version number added to it. You can wait for a couple seconds and then move to the first page of your app. Its not a super elegant solution but if you need it to scale properly for multiple devices you cannot use the xib for the launch file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution. @Allen